# Can't sign in into Microsoft teams ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, microsoft-teams

I started using microsoft teams, probably because skype will be murdered by end of july, I'm able to sign in into microsoft teams in my phone, windows version(.exe file) but I can't sign in into ubuntu version(.deb file) I think that it is probably problem with ubuntu version, anyone know some work around other than using teams as a site.

Comment: According to your description, your issue is more related to Teams product, which we do not support. For issues related to teams product, please reach out to the [Product support channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels) for Microsoft Teams.

Comment: ok Chetana-MSFT